# I'm being bullied/targeted by 2 moderators what can I do about it?

Tags: discussion, moderation

there was a fake account made be a moderator and when my answers were upvoted instead of that account my account started to be targeted by a moderator

now that account has disappeared and a million and one new accounts have appeared!

and now my old awnsers have been targeted and every day I get -2 points. that's not an issue but it shows somthing dodgy is going on

down voted on questions that noone answered 
so no answers added just downvoting!

as well as my answers being deleted by a moderator for "plagiarism" when its obviously not the case

when I flag these issues on answers they simply get dismissed by the moderator in question themselves!

is this normal on stack?

Updated:
and now they are targeting me here as well! and the person that accused me ofplagiarism is saying I should stop making accusations!

update: they have now both downvoted my question and someone deleted my comments! that was asking why they deleted my answer.

is it ok to push away regular users that contribute on stack ? 
is it not true that we should be encouraging more content creation instead of pushing new dedicated users away?

my comments on the answer have been hidden not sure why as there has been no explanation

dose that mean stack shadow bans some users?

if so then what's the point of supporting and contributing when a mod can just delete your answers and not even tell you why

Answer (score 2):

> there was a fake account made be a moderator and when my answers were upvoted instead of that account my account started to be targeted by a moderator

If you think the moderators on this site have been acting inappropriately, you can use the "Contact" link at the bottom of every page to complain directly to Stack Exchange.

> now that account has disappeared and a million and one new accounts have appeared!

The "million and one new accounts" is a gross exaggeration; the most recent user at the time of writing has id 28060.

> and now my old awnsers have been targeted and every day I get -2 points. on answers where there are non so no answers added just downvoting!

People are free to vote as they see fit.

> as well as my answers being deleted by a moderator for "plagiarism" when its (sic) obviously not the case

Please see [How to reference material written by others](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) in the [Help Center](/help).

> when I flag these issues on answers they simply get dismissed by the moderator in question

No, I looked for evidence of targeted voting with the limited tools available to moderators, and didn't find any. At least one of the other moderators did the same. Contacting Stack Exchange directly may be your best option if you think additional investigation is justified.

> is this normal on stack?

Again, contact Stack Exchange directly.

Comment: ok calm down why are you so angry about this? "a million and one " is an English expression it means a few or a bag of them

Comment: Not angry, just being factual.

Comment: Niall C. gave you the precise details about how you can proceed if you think that we moderators have been doing something wrong. We are not emotional. We do however have a clear set of rules  for fulfilling the role that the community has entrusted us with. You may rest assured that the moderators on this site will discuss every action beyond the most mundane activities, and in almost all cases _before_ taking action.

Comment: @seedelicious Please stop this kind of accusations.

Comment: @seedelicious Use the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page if you want Stack Exchange staff to look at your case.